# uncaught exception: SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have created a new collection :

```
db.createCollection("1st_Year_Students")
```

I am trying to add an object to this collection :

```
db.1st_Year_Students.insert({FullName : "Test Test"})
```

I am having this error :

> uncaught exception: SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after
> numeric literal : @(shell):1:2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongo Shell does not recognise the collection name because its started from number and causes the error,

> **[Restriction on Collection Names](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#mongodb-limit-Restriction-on-Collection-Names):**
>
> *If your collection name includes special characters, such as the underscore character, or begins with numbers, then to access the collection use the `db.getCollection()` method in the mongo shell or a similar method for your driver.*

```
db.getCollection('1st_Year_Students').insert({FullName : "Test Test"})
```